# How to avoid duplicating a periodic task when using await Task.Delay inside a while loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, while-loop, async-await

I am doing a periodic task as given below from inside a Page A's viewmodel constructor

```
async void RunPeriodicTask()
{
  while(true)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));

    //periodic task
  }
}
```

Now there is a scenario where i navigate from Page B to Page A which calls the Page A's viewmodel constructor.

As a result the second periodic task is done again on top of the existing periodic task.

Please help how i can stop the periodic task from happening more than once.

I tried to use the CancellationTokenSource to cancel the thread from Page B but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: You have to add [cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children) support, so when you leave current page task get cancelled.

Comment: the periodic task runs across the application so i cannot cancel it when i leave the page.

Comment: Then the viewmodel is not the right place for it. Maybe create some sort of scheduling service.

Comment: Well, you can prevent another task from starting if one from another page is still running. It's all about using proper synchronization, so there are many possibilities.

Comment: Why have you put this inside the viewmodel? The model should only transfer data from the server to the client.

Comment: Why did you opted for [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) instead of `async Task`?

Comment: Since i was calling it from inside the constructor i had used the async void on the method. Now i changed it to async Task and now i am able to handle this scenario using the cancellationtokensource and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used a delegate in Page A viewmodel to cancel the task from Page B, now the current task is replaced by a new task.

```
ViewModel() //constructor
    {
      HandlePeriodicTask();
    }
    
    async void HandlePeriodicTask()
    {
      try
      { 
        await RunPeriodicTaskAsync()
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
      {
        //logs
      }
    }
    
    async Task RunPeriodicTaskAsync()
    {
      _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
      while(true)
      {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), token);
    
        //periodic task
    
      }
    }
```